# Heroku Cedar Python: requirement in github - clone fails with error 128

Tags: python, git, heroku, pip

i wanted to use the pyfire github library https://github.com/mariano/pyfire

this is what pip freeze produced for me:

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/mariano/pyfire.git@db856bb666c4b381c08f2f4bf7c9ac7aaa233221#egg=pyfire-dev
```

but when doing so the clone that is being done to install the dependencies fails with error code, i can't

```
heroku run console
```

to check out the full error log...

any experience with this or ideas?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Aside, you should run `heroku run bash`, not `console`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip freeze appears to produce the wrong results you should be able to modify your requirements.txt to:

```
git+https://github.com/mariano/pyfire.git@db856bb666c4b381c08f2f4bf7c9ac7aaa233221#egg=pyfire-dev
```

Comment: yeah grabbing the archive like that fixed it for me^^ but i talked to the pyfire guy already and its on pypi now anyhow so i am good

Comment: Having the same problem and this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: how about jut using pypi to install it?

Answer (score 1):

I realized this was already solved for you, but this didn't work for me or @amrox or @tomtaylor.

If you remove the commit part, it works for me. i.e. changing the line in requirements.txt to:

```
git+https://github.com/mariano/pyfire.git
```

When I install the git repo including the specific commit locally, git seems to realize the end part is a specific commit, but when I try this on heroku and track the progress, it is pretty clear it is treating the commit part as a tag. Since there is no tag with that name, that's why it fails. They may be using a different version of git.